# Add activity background image in full screen behind transaparent Actionbar

Tags: java, android, xml

I have created a Transparent ActionBar and i want to show the full image that will cover the action bar also but my image comes down below the action bar.
[I want my image to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXjMy.png)
But instead my image look like this [My Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoBlG.jpg).

My style for transparent Actionbar

```
Styles.xml

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
  <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

My Activity where i want to show the full size image

```
Activity

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/containerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"                 /*This is the action bar*/                                                        
        layout="@layout/appbartransparent"></include>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/views"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</LinearLayout>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation1"
    android:name="com.example.asad.homebuyerproject.NavigationBar"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigationdrawerwidth"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Move to `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` theme and put a `Toolbar` directly in your view hierarchy.

Comment: @EugenPechanec but this will not solve my problem because it will also take its space,i think their should be other way to do it

Comment: Use `FrameLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`. Don't forget to put the toolbar *after* the content in XML.

Comment: @EugenPechanec thanks it will worked